# Laravel 4 | Catchable fatal error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I try Laravel 4 but get error

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Container\Container::share() must be an instance of Closure, unknown given, called in /host/sites/centos6/laravel4/bootstrap/compiled.php on line 3131 and defined in /host/sites/centos6/laravel4/bootstrap/compiled.php on line 98
```

please help me, thanks all

*ps: sorry for my english*

Comment: Could you please share some more code, specifically anything you might have done recently that may have caused the error. You might also try deleting the `bootstrap/compiled.php` file.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your public/index.php file:

```
ini_set('eaccelerator.enable', 0);
```